# How to Click On Group Add Member through facebook

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I want to click on group add button of Facebook, but I have not found it possible using an xpath.

Here is the html for the button:

```html
<li>
  <a 
    class="_42ft _4jy0 _3-8i _4jy3 _517h _51sy" 
    role="button" 
    href="#" 
    ajaxify="/ajax/groups/members/add_get.php?group_id=1168192579894018&amp;refresh=1" 
    rel="dialog">
      <i class="_3-8_ img sp__lkuGKPb9f- sx_e8790e"></i>
    Add
  </a>
</li>
```

This is how I have tried to click on it:

```java
JavascriptExecutor jse1 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse1.executeScript("document.getElementById('gbqfb').click‌​();");
```

Comment: Please add the html section with the button if possible.

Comment: JavascriptExecutor jse1 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse1.executeScript("document.getElementById('gbqfb').click();");        Html Code is given below :                                                                  <li><a class="_42ft _4jy0 _3-8i _4jy3 _517h _51sy" role="button" href="#" ajaxify="/ajax/groups/members/add_get.php?group_id=1168192579894018&amp;refresh=1" rel="dialog"><i class="_3-8_ img sp__lkuGKPb9f- sx_e8790e"></i>Add</a></li>

Comment: Please use "edit" button instead of comment to add code.

Comment: I have restructured your question a little bit, to make it more readable. Remember that you are encouraged to [edit] and re-edit your question to make it as clear and useful as possible. I recommend adding in the xpath you have tried to use, and a description of why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `xpath` as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(.,'Add')]")).click();
```

Or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[normalize-space() = 'Add']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the id that you are using.

You can try with the following css selector:

```css
a[href*='groups/members/add'][href*='116819257‌​9894018']
```

The first href assure that you are clicking the add for the group, 
the second href assures that you are clicking add for the right group

I don't know how the page is looking, if you have only one add then you can remove the second href.

If if you can get the selector with css then for sure you can get it with xpath.
I recommend using css.